# Selecting an element that doesn't have a child with a certain class

Tags: css, css-selectors

The structure of my HTML is like so

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>Something</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 class='Handle'>Something</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the event that the `div > div` does not have a child with the class "Handle" I want the the `div > div` to have the style `cursor:move;`. How would I go about doing this in pure CSS, is it even possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible in pure css, your asking about doing an `if` check on a piece of the dom. Which would properly be done in javascript.

Comment: In my case, I needed to select only "top-level" tables (i.e. tables that don't have any tables nested inside them), and ended up with `table:not(table table)`, which is the goofiest css selector I've ever written.

Answer (score 32):

## `:not(:has())`

***Note: Limited support for old browsers.***

The example below demonstrates the combination of the [`:not()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#has-pseudo)
and **[`:has()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#has-pseudo)**
pseudo-classes to select elements that do not have a specified child.

```css
div:not(:has(p)) {
  background: powderblue;
}
div:not(:has(p)):hover {
  color: blue;
  background: azure;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Does Not Have a Paragraph</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Has a Paragraph</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

*As of March 2024, `:has()` is [supported by most modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility). However, Firefox only recently implemented support for `:has` in release 121 (dated 2023-12-19.) So, use with caution if old browsers are used by clients.
`:not()` has been supported [since 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) by most browsers.*

*Alternatively, jQuery supports the [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.*

Comment: Has support for this been newly implemented?

Comment: Damien, no it hasn't. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: FYI, this [appears to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71401290/6243352) in Python's BeautifulSoup!

Comment: This looks to be fully supported by modern browsers. https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: @Patrick With 89.06% global usage as of December 26th, 2023, which isn't too bad. But if these styles are dealing with a very important feature that will appear broken otherwise, you still may want to think it twice.

Comment: @GerardReches I understand your concern but at some point you have to cut your losses. Its simply pointless to try to achieve perfection in all browsers in all versions in the last say 10 years.

Comment: @Patrick And I totally agree with that. If it were for me I would ignore anything that is not an up-to-date Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Edge. Unfortunately, clients often request compatibility for any browser/device where they find the website isn't working as expected, including IE and non-updated browsers, which many times stops us from moving forward.

Answer (score 5):

There is no parent selector in CSS, so what you are asking is not possible. What you can do is put the `cursor:move` on every h1 that doesnt has the class "Handle" by using the attribute selector.

```
h1:not([class=Handle]) {
    cursor:move;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4HLGF/

Another option is to adjust your HTML, and move your h1 on the same level as the div.

```
<div>
    <h1>Something</h1>
    <div>
        dragable content
    </div>
    <h1 class='Handle'>Something</h1>
    <div>
        non dragable content
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can do the same check on the h1, and target the div that comes after it.

```
h1:not([class=Handle]) + div {
    cursor:move;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4HLGF/2/

Comment: Your first solution doesn't work because it will select the h1 and if the h1 doesn't have the class then it needs to select the parent (div).

And your second solution isn't possible because it isn't fixed HTML. Every div has to be able to be moved freely on its own so the H1 has to be inside it.

Comment: @user1763295 Maybe you should read better, in my answer i specificly said that it is not possible to select the div based on the children's class since there is no such thing as a parent selector in css! I was giving alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Is this enough for this purpose?

```css
div > div:not(:has(.Handle)):not(:empty) {
    cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>Something</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 class='Handle'>Something</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
div > div h1:not([class=Handle]) {
    cursor:move;
}
```

Comment: That will give the `<h1>` the `cursor: move;` declaration, not the `<div>`