# I want to select a child element select without a parent element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```html
1  <div class="mnr-c xpd O9g5cc uUPGi">
2   <div>
3    <div class="mnr-c xpd O9g5cc uUPGi">someting</div>
4   </div>
5   <div>
6    <div class="mnr-c xpd O9g5cc uUPGi">someting</div>
7   </div>
8  </div>
9  <div class="mnr-c xpd O9g5cc uUPGi">someting</div>
10
```

I have an HTML structure like above. I just want to select child elements using CSS selectors but parents and children have the same classes. If I try to select using jquery for example `$$(".mnr-c.xpd.O9g5cc.uUPGi").forEach(el => console.log(el))` that method show 4 result but I just want to see 3 result. Lines 1,9 and 11 are on the same level. My purpose just take lines 3rd and 6th and 9 lines. How I can prevent select a parent element. Is something like this possible just using CSS or jquery?

Comment: Use the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) `$(".O9g5cc .O9g5cc")`, [CSS Child vs Descendant selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182189/css-child-vs-descendant-selectors)

Comment: Possibly answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189147/selecting-an-element-that-doesnt-have-a-child-with-a-certain-class/53173276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS doesn't have an option to check contents (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189147/selecting-an-element-that-doesnt-have-a-child-with-a-certain-class/53173276))

With jquery, you can select the elements that are children, then get their parents and exclude those parents:

```
var parents = $(".xpd .xpd").parents(".xpd")
var selection = $(".xpd").not(parents)
```

Note this must be `.xpd .xpd` and not `.xpd > .xpd` as there's a `div` in-between the two levels, so they're not "children"

Giving:

```js
var sel = $(".xpd").not($(".xpd .xpd").parents(".xpd"))
console.log(sel.length)
sel.each((i,e) => console.log(e))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mnr-c xpd O9g5cc uUPGi">
  <div>
   <div class="mnr-c xpd O9g5cc uUPGi">something 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div class="mnr-c xpd O9g5cc uUPGi">something 2</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mnr-c xpd O9g5cc uUPGi">something 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is the children, then you can select via [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>`, like this `$(".mnr-c.xpd.O9g5cc.uUPGi > .mnr-c.xpd.O9g5cc.uUPGi")`.

if you want all the descendants of the element with the same class, you can use the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)    (empty space), like this `$(".mnr-c.xpd.O9g5cc.uUPGi .mnr-c.xpd.O9g5cc.uUPGi")`.

Comment: The HTML the OP shows indicates that those are not the children but the descendants

Comment: Yes, but in his question he also asks about children, so I provided an answer for both cases. This is probably a simplified example of the actual code, for all we know.

Comment: Thank you, George, I forgot to write some places lines 1,9,10 and 11 are on the same level. My purpose take lines 3rd and 6th and 9 10 11 lines. Is something like this possible just using CSS or jquery?

Comment: @omrsfylmz please update your question with your requirement / example.  Your question states you want 2 results, but your comment above indicates 5.

Comment: @freedomn-m I updated it, is it understandable now?

Answer (score -1):

Use a descendant combinator:

```js
$(".mnr-c.xpd.O9g5cc.uUPGi .mnr-c.xpd.O9g5cc.uUPGi").forEach(el => console.log(el));
```

```css
.mnr-c.xpd.O9g5cc.uUPGi .mnr-c.xpd.O9g5cc.uUPGi {
    border: 2px dotted red;
}
```

[Descendant combinator | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)