# CSS for element without any grandchild elements

Tags: css

how to specify CSS for an element without any grandchild elements? e.g.,

```
<div class="foo">
   <ul></ul>
</div>

<div class="foo">
   <ul><li></li></ul>
</div>

// hide the <div> whose child <ul> is empty, how?
div.foo {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: CSS currently does not support `:has()`, you must use JavaScript as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189147/selecting-an-element-that-doesnt-have-a-child-with-a-certain-class/53173276), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700262/is-it-possible-to-select-elements-that-do-not-have-a-child-of-a-certain-type)

Comment: can XPath be used in CSS?  div.foo[count(ul/li)=0] {...}

Comment: There are no `count()` in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Hey there is `:empty` selector in css which allows you to do like this.

#### Javascript method to get what you asked for

But If you want to hide other things you should use *javascript*

`:has` is experimental
A simple way of doing this

```js
let text = document.querySelector("div.foo > ul");
if(text.innerHTML == ""){
// set your things
document.querySelector("div.foo").style.display = "none";
// you can delete this thing too but this is just an examplee
}
```

#### using :empty selector

If you don't wanna use javascript then this method is also good

Simply use

```css
div > ul:empty{
display:none; // or any styles that you can see
}
```

For just illustration purpose :

```css
div.foo > ul{
background-color:blue;
height:30px;
}

div.foo > ul:empty{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Below is empty ul -->
<div class="foo">
<ul></ul>
</div>
<!-- Below is non empty ul -->
<div class="foo">
<ul>
<li>This is with  text</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

But be carefull

> Empty elements are elements that have nothing in them. It cannot even have a whitespace.

There is something called `:blank` but it is experimental as far as I know.

Comment: This will be hide on `ul` not `div`. The OP want to hide `div`.

Comment: Your updated answer (JS) should work. Upvote for this. :-)