# How to filter tag without an attribute in find_all() function in Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags, findall

Below are a simple html source code I'm working with

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to the comments assignment from www.py4e.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This file contains the actual data for your assignment - good luck!</h1>

<table border="2">
<tr>
<td>Name</td><td>Comments</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Melodie</td><td><span class="comments">100</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Machaela</td><td><span class="comments">100</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Rhoan</td><td><span class="comments">99</span></td></tr>
```

Below is my code try to get the `<td>Melodie</td>` line

```
html='html text file aboved'

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    for tag in soup.find_all('td'):
        print(tag) 
        print('----') #Result:
#===============================================================================
# <td>Name</td>
# ----
# <td>Comments</td>
# ----
# <td>Melodie</td>
# ----
# <td><span class="comments">100</span></td>
# ----
# <td>Machaela</td>
# ----
# <td><span class="comments">100</span></td>
# ----
# <td>Rhoan</td>
# ----
#.........
#===============================================================================
```

Now I want to get the `<td>name<td>` lines only and not the line with 'span' and 'class'. I try 2 filters `soup.find_all('td' and not 'span')` and `soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':None})` but none of those work. I know there is other way around but I want to use the filter in soup.find_all().
My expected output (actually my final goal is to get the name of person between two `<td>`):

```
# <td>Name</td>
# ----
# <td>Comments</td>
# ----
# <td>Melodie</td>
# ----
# <td>Machaela</td>
# ----
# <td>Rhoan</td>
# ----
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding what exactly you want to scrape. Can you share the expected output?

Comment: Hi I edited my expected output on my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your elements via `css selectors` e.g. nest [pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) `:has()` and `:not()`:

```
soup.select('td:not(:has(span))')
```

or

```
soup.select('td:not(:has(.comments))')
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1430669.html').read()

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for e in soup.select('td:not(:has(span))'):
    print(e)
```

#### Output

```
<td>Name</td>
<td>Comments</td>
<td>Melodie</td>
<td>Machaela</td>
<td>Rhoan</td>
<td>Murrough</td>
<td>Lilygrace</td>
...
```

Comment: Nice answer -- I hadn't tried the `:not()` syntax yet in bs. Learned something new.

Comment: Thank you. But may I ask what do ":" means in soup.select? Can you briefly explain to me? I read the documentation about Beautifulsoup and find soup.select command, but it doesn't mention anything about using ":" (colon)

Comment: @ggorlen: Level 3 CSS specification states with `:not()` only supports simple selectors, but I like nesting / chaining of `css selectors` to avoid multiple selector calls.

Comment: @QuangHoàngMinh: Added a link to [css pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) if you like to get further information.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the desired output with two separate selector calls:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<body>
<table border="2">
<tr>
<td>Name</td><td>Comments</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Melodie</td><td><span class="comments">100</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Machaela</td><td><span class="comments">100</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Rhoan</td><td><span class="comments">99</span></td></tr>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for elem in soup.select("td"):
    if not elem.select(".comments"):
        print(elem)
```

Output:

```
<td>Name</td>
<td>Comments</td>
<td>Melodie</td>
<td>Machaela</td>
<td>Rhoan</td>
```

As an aside, prefer lxml to html.parser. It's faster and more robust to malformed HTML.

Comment: May I ask why for the if line when I change to for elem1 in elem.select(':not(.comments)') print(elem1) it doesn't work? I've just learned about CSS pseudo-class and I found the :not. Still doesn't work

Comment: If you want to use the pseudoselector approach, the correct syntax is shown in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71401290/6243352). Is there a problem with using that?

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been 12 months since the question was posted, but I hope this can help those who will come after us. I have tried and tried to find the most concise code for a beginner like me. Here it is:

```
#Creating the veariables
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
my_list = list()

#Asking BeautifulSoup to find all <td> tags that contains strings only with lettes (a-zA-z)
names = soup.find_all("td", string = re.compile("[a-zA-Z]"))

for name in names:
    my_list.append(name)
    print(name)

print(my_list)
```